# Can swapping ignition coils fix a cylinder four misfire?

Tags: hyundai, misfire, ignition-coil, i20

My car was having power issues so I took it to the mechanic who said cylinder 4 was misfiring. He came back to me and said he swapped the ignition coils over and rescanned with no misfires and told me to pick it up, and to bring ti back if there was any more issues.

Im a bit confused as to how that would fix the problem.

Car is a 2012 Hyundai i20 1.4L 4 cylinder

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It normally wouldn't, however, I'm thinking the problem might have been the wiring connector to the coil wasn't making a good connection (or possibly causing an intermittent connection), which was causing the misfire. When the coils was changed around, a good connection was re-established, which allowed the coil to fire regularly once again. This is just a suggestion of what might have happened, but it seems plausible to me.

Two things:

1. If this was the case, you'll most likely have the same problem occur in the future, so don't be surprised.
2. The mechanic was spot on for testing the coil in this method.

Bottom line, I don't think I'd worry too much about it.

Comment: What's to the point is that if a dirty connection has been fixed by moving the coils, it's fruitless now to try and find out what the fault was.  The best you can do is drive on and wait for the problem to re-occur.